# How can I translate an object along its local axis using a script?

Tags: python, transforms, shortcut

I have a cube.

The cube's Z rotation is 45 degrees.

If I press <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd>, I can move the object along its local X axis.

How can I do this with a Python script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?350682-Local-tranforms&p=2739967&viewfull=1#post2739967).

```
  import bpy
  from mathutils import Vector, Matrix

  ...

  trans_local = Vector((0.0, 32.0, 0.0))
  trans_world = obj.matrix_world.to_3x3() * trans_local
  obj.matrix_world.translation += trans_world
```

Comment: or simply obj.location += Vector( (32, 0, 0) )

Comment: @lemon - That's giving me a much different result. Are you sure that that works for local translation?

Comment: You are right : I have badly read the question

Comment: > Blender 2.8: Use `@`instead of `*` for the matrix multiplication.